# vim autocommand doesn't run when opening file

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using [QuickCursor](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor) for entering text to forms.
My problem with that is I always have MacVim open, and with `hidden` enabled, so when I `:wq` from the temp file QuickCursor make, the buffer stays in MacVim, so I have to delete it to get QuickCursor paste back to the window.
I wanted to solve this with an autocommand in my vimrc:
`autocmd BufRead "/private/var/folders/fg/gv_*/T/*" set bufhidden="delete" | startinsert!`
but this never run. What could be the problem ? What is the right event to use ? I tried BufWinEnter, BufNewFile, neither of them works, or maybe something else is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after several hours of try, I finally found out.

I had added quotes to the `bufhidden` setting and the filename. It should be:

```
autocmd BufRead /private/var/folders/fg/gv_*/T/* set bufhidden=delete | startinsert!
```

With the extra quotes it doesn't work:

- "delete" is an invalid option value (see [`:he bufhidden`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27bufhidden%27))
- quotes around a filename prevent the wildcards (*glob characters*) from matching (see [doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#file-searching))

If anybody else using QuickCursor, you can fine-tune it:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter /private/var/folders/fg/gv_*/T/* set bufhidden=delete |
    exe "normal G$" | startinsert!
```

So it changes to insert mode at the end of the text